# Pure Sine Inverters and Transformer Selection

Tags: transformer, ac, inverter, component-selection, pricing

So I'm trying to design a 24V to 110V pure sine wave inverter, which I'd like to be able to do 2000W to handle running my portable A/C on battery. I get the whole H-Bridge MOSFET concept, and even built a prototype board to test with my scope. (I'm not quite sure what exact capacitor sizing I should go with for the final thing, but I get the concept in theory, just make a sine wave with PWM, smooth it out with big capacitor, and run it through a transformer)

The thing is, transformer pricing is really bugging me. Transformers are super expensive to buy on their own for some reason. Made-in-US vendors seem to charge thousands for a basic 2kVA transformer, and even with the cheapest I can find on Ali Express, it's at least $250 w/ shipping! *(Also I believe these are 220V transformers so I'd have to select the 48V one to get 110V out on 24V, but they're the same price anyhow)*
[image: Sine Wave Transformer]

But this doesn't add up when you look at other 2000W inverters! Here's one for only ~$175! *Note: It says 5000W but that's just the peak power, continuous is 2500W.*
[image: 2500W Inverter Ali Express]

Of course you could say that no-name Chinese inverter is a little sus, so fine, let's look at one from Amazon instead. A pure sine 2kW continuous inverter for only $265, and that's with ONE DAY shipping, and it has a screen. You're telling me that the transformer is nearly 100% of the cost with no profit margin? I don't think so.
[image: 2000W Inverter Amazon]

So what gives!? All the info about building a pure sine inverter I found online pointed to needing a transformer that matches the wattage of the output... So either these guys have a top secret source for cheap transformers, or maybe their circuit cheats somehow to use a smaller one? Or none at all?

Comment: Do you believe the transformer would cost the same thing if you bought 5,000 of them?

Comment: Do you think shipping a pallet of 5,000 transformers would be cheaper than shipping 5,000 transformers one at a time?

Comment: Good point. But while the transformer is heavy and thus pricy to ship in quantity of 1, doesn't that mean the inverter is even heavier? So it should also cost the same or more to ship in quantity of 1. Oh well, perhaps some things just aren't very cost effective to try to design yourself... That would be a shame though. Many things are actually cheaper the DIY route, even WITH the added price of small parts orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a high 50/60 Hz transformer cost you can use a powerful and cheaper DC-to-DC converter to "up" your DC voltage from 24 volts to 160 volts using a 100 kHz switching frequency then, use your H-bridge directly on the high DC voltage.

> *just make a sine wave with PWM, smooth it out with big capacitor*

Ha ha no!!! You need an LC low-pass filter; the capacitor would just short out the PWM output and make molten metal quickly.

Comment: And your A/C doesn't really need a pure sinewave

Comment: @Andy aka Not according to the paper that Texas Instruments wrote, it says to do just that and put a large capacitor at the transformer output to smooth the PWM to a sine wave.
Also, would it really be practical to boost the DC that high and then switch it using MOSFETs? I suppose it would lower the switch current which would probably mean less heat(?) I would have to select MOSFETs and gate drivers that can handle that much voltage. Not to mention it would take one beefy boost converter.

Comment: @jp314 You'd think so, but tell that to my 2kW APC UPS with a modified wave inverter that causes my AC to get ANGY and shut itself off. It also makes the motors in my A/C (and any other fan I plug in) to sound slightly weird. I think it's maybe causing an increase in current draw in the AC motors that causes the A/C control board to think something is wrong.

Comment: @Pecacheu your words in your question are: *smooth it out with big capacitor, and run it through a transformer* <-- in other words, you said put it before the transformer and not on the transformer output. Anyway, if you put it at the transformer output (as you say in comments) then you need leakage inductance inside the transformer to play a role AND you need to understand its value

Comment: @Pecacheu you said: *Also, would it really be practical to boost the DC that high and then switch it using MOSFETs?* and my answer is **absolutely**. I'm working on designing an 80 kW (kilowatts) 600 volt H-bridge at this moment, well, not right now, right now I'm having a beer.

Comment: Damn, that's one hell of an H-bridge. Would probably even put the one in my EV to shame, lol. If that's the case though, I will probably opt for the HV DC method instead of using a transformer... It will definitely be lighter weight, and hopefully cheaper too. And don't worry, I have worked with HV DC before, it's AC that's my weak point and I will probably blow something up on that side. XD. Fire safety first I guess

Comment: Also, I take it that means I need to use some sort of low-pass filter instead of just a capacitor across the output? Weird, I am pretty sure they make devices that are literally just a giant capacitor across the AC lines. Don't HVACs contain them?

Comment: Update: I built an inverter with high-voltage DC and with a low pass filter in a circuit sim, along with a low pass filter (using a formula I found). The filter seems to work... But only when the current is exactly what was used in the formula, on a light load it doesn't smooth out the sine wave :/ But I guess that is the topic for a new question at that point.

Comment: @Pecacheu yes, the filtering can be a real pain on wide load variations but it is solvable generally with a little relaxation of the sine smoothness requirements.